# Assign event handling delegate in static factory method

Tags: c#, .net

I strongly suspect I shouldn't be using a static factory method here, but for the mean time I am at a loss how to implement this.  The following code gives a compile error on the line in `CreateOpenPort` that assigns `_currentPort_DataReceived` because that delegate method isn't static.  How can I resolve this, preferably using a non-static factory method?

```
    public static SerialPortService CreateOpenPort(string portName, int baudRate, Parity parity, int dataBits, StopBits stopBits)
    {
        var service = new SerialPortService
                          {
                              _currentPort = new SerialPort(portName, baudRate, parity, dataBits, stopBits)
                          };
        service._currentPort.DataReceived += CurrentPortCharsReceived;
        service._currentPort.Open();
        return service;
    }

void CurrentPortCharsReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    var port = (SerialPort) sender;

    var chars = new char[port.BytesToRead];
    var x = port.Read(chars, 0, chars.Length);
    OnDataReceived(chars.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, static factory with a **static** handler is not so bad an idea although I will try avoiding them for the sake of unit tests.

Implement a **singleton** pattern if there is going it be only one instance in the AppDomain. That will be *clean* and *working*.

Comment: How does a static handler deal with concurrent events from multiple SerialPort instances?  Does it queue them?

Comment: They will be running in their own copy of the static method. However, if you are touching any static state, you need to make sure you are synchronised.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Singleton pattern, which removes the need for CreateOpenPort to be static:

```
public class SerialPortService{

static private service = new SerialPortService();

private SerialPortService(){}

public static GetInstance()
{
   return service;
}

public SerialPortService CreateOpenPort(string portName, int baudRate, Parity parity, int dataBits, StopBits stopBits) 
{ 
    var port = new SerialPort(portName, baudRate, parity, dataBits, stopBits); 
    port.DataReceived += _currentPort_DataReceived;             
    port.Open(); 
    return port; 
} 

void _currentPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    var port = (SerialPort) sender; 

    var chars = new char[port.BytesToRead]; 
    var x = port.Read(chars, 0, chars.Length); 
    OnDataReceived(chars.ToString()); 
}
```

Comment: I need multiple instances of SerialPortService, or if I use a singleton I need to manage a private collection SerialPort instances.  The latter option is too complex for my task at hand.

Comment: I don't understand your design. If you have multiple instances of SerialPortService and each one manages the SerialPorts they create, then why is the CreatePort() method static? How are you managing them in your current design?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you give away the ports when you are handling the incoming data? It's like asking for trouble.

The code that calls your factory method can (and probably will) handle the incoming data (as will the class defining the factory). And that can give you unexpected behavior.

I suggest that you think through what you want to do and ask again.

Comment: I am asking a general design question, and what parameters I pass have very little bearing on that question.  Code I used in my EXAMPLE is very early, proof of concept code.  I thought my question through enough, thank you.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong. I really want to help you. But it's easier if you describe what you want to achieve. I might figure out an alternative design.